# How to limit web service access to one client?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service written in Java, and it has 2 almost identical clients that access its methods. The only difference is that one client is an "admin" client.

However, there is a requirement that the admin client can at any time he wants, stop the other client from accessing the web service, or to be particular, a few of its methods.

How would such a thing be accomplished? I guess there could be a way to define that the web service could only be accessed by a specific client in the web service's code? Is there some way (I'm asking for generic technologies or concepts, not direct code here btw) this can be done? Or is there some other way it needs to be done?

EDIT:My clients are Java applications running on Windows

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan I haven't tried anything yet, and I couldn't find anything on Google or StackOverflow either. I was hypothesizing that there may be a way that the web service itself could say that it could only be called by a particular client, so that that function, could be called via a web method

Comment: Don't expect StackOverflow to provide you with ready-made solutions. That's [not the way problem-solving is done](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). This site is for help with specific programming problems, and questions are expected to show some research effort.

Comment: @RealSkeptic well as I said, I can't find anything on Google for this problem. I believed that this requirement is merely rare, and the concept behind this might be known by someone on StackOverflow

Comment: This concept is not rare, it's extremely common. You just need to identify the client with some kind of login, token or anything. But StackOverflow it's not here to "discuss" about what to do or implement, you need to have a specific problem, coding related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with web services, you may have noticed that some of them require an access token to make requests.

An access token is an opaque string that identifies a user, app, or page and can be used by the app to make API calls.

So, you might want to implement it in your java code so that only a authorized client can make a request to it.

In your case, another simpler solution would be to use some sort of flag/indicator to know the request has been sent by admin and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component / service / object / whatever-your-framework-names-it that holds the flag "Is the non-admin allowed to connect" (you could possibly extend your current authorization model with it). Perform a check on each resource that might be affected; set/reset it via the admin path or a dedicated resource.